# How to evaluate a constructed string with non-standard evaluation using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, nse, rlang, tidyeval

I have read several guides on programming with **dplyr** now and I am still confused about how to solve the problem of evaluating constructed/concatenated strings with non-standard evaluation (NSE). I realize that there are better ways to solve this example than using NSE, but want to learn how to.

```
t <- tibble( x_01 = c(1, 2, 3), x_02 = c(4, 5, 6))
i <- 1
```

This is my desired outcome but want the variables in `mutate()` to be constructed:

```
t %>% mutate(d_01 = x_01 * 2)
#>   A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   x_01  x_02  d_01
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  1.00  4.00  2.00
#> 2  2.00  5.00  4.00
#> 3  3.00  6.00  6.00
```

This is my first attempt, trying to use strings:

```
new <- sprintf("d_%02d", i)
var <- sprintf("x_%02d", i)
t %>% mutate(new = var * 2)
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#> Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
```

This is my second attempt, trying to use quosures:

```
new <- rlang::quo(sprintf("d_%02d", i))
var <- rlang::quo(sprintf("x_%02d", i))
t %>% mutate(!!new = !!var * 2)
#> Error: unexpected '=' in "t %>% mutate(!!new ="
```

This is my third attempt, trying to use quosures and the `:=` operator:

```
new <- rlang::quo(sprintf("d_%02d", i))
var <- rlang::quo(sprintf("x_%02d", i))
t %>% mutate(!!new := !!var * 2)
#> Error in var * 2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sym` and `:=` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

t <- tibble( x_01 = c(1, 2, 3), x_02 = c(4, 5, 6))
i <- 1

new <- sym(sprintf("d_%02d", i))
var <- sym(sprintf("x_%02d", i))
t %>% mutate(!!new := (!!var) * 2)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
   x_01  x_02  d_01
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4     2
2     2     5     4
3     3     6     6
```

Also note that this is trivial in base R:

```
tdf <- data.frame( x_01 = c(1, 2, 3), x_02 = c(4, 5, 6))
i <- 1

new <- sprintf("d_%02d", i)
var <- sprintf("x_%02d", i)
tdf[[new]] <- 2 * tdf[[var]]
```

Comment: Thanks! So, you use `sym()` when you want the expression to be resolved first?

Comment: Use `sym` when we have a *character string*.

Answer (score 2):

You might find package [`friendlyeval`](https://github.com/MilesMcBain/friendlyeval) useful while learning tidy eval. It simplifies the API and makes function choice clear in cases like these.

You have two strings you want to use as column names, so you can write:

```
t <- tibble( x_01 = c(1, 2, 3), x_02 = c(4, 5, 6))
i <- 1

new <- sprintf("d_%02d", i)
var <- sprintf("x_%02d", i)
t %>% mutate(!!treat_string_as_col(new) := 
               !!treat_string_as_col(var) * 2)
```

You can convert from `friendlyeval` code to plain tidy eval code at any time using an RStudio addin. This may be helpful given your learning goal.