# dplyr . and _no visible binding for global variable '.'_ Note in package check

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, magrittr

In `dplyr` one can write code like e.g. using the '.' to refer to the data in the pipe

```
x <- data.frame(x = 2:4)
y <- data.frame(y = 1:3)

y %>% dplyr::bind_cols(x,.)
```

but when using it in a function and running the package check it produces the

> no visible binding for global variable '.'.

What is the best practice to handle the NOTE?

Answer (score 15):

It seems that best practice is to use `.data` instead of `.` and then use import `.data` from the `rlang` package. From the [programming with `dplyr` vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html):

> If this function is in a package, using .data also prevents R CMD check from giving a NOTE about undefined global variables (provided that you’ve also imported rlang::.data with @importFrom rlang .data).

Unfortunately that doesn't work for the original question with `dplyr::bind_cols`, but it works for example in `dplyr::mutate` and `dplyr::do`.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like the way to go. As soon as I tried it I will accept your answer. Have a great day.

Comment: It does not work either with e.g. `all_vars(. < 3)` applications or `any_vars(. < 4)` etc.

Answer (score 8):

Best practice now is to probably use quosures. This other SO post has a good summary: [How to evaluate a constructed string with non-standard evaluation using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053187/how-to-evaluate-a-constructed-string-with-non-standard-evaluation-using-dplyr/48053325#48053325)

In practice, I've just included `. = NULL` at the top of my functions.

**EDIT**

As @MrFlick pointed out, quosures won't actually help in this case. You can feasibly use quosures to define column names etc. in a way that would allow you to avoid notes about non-standard evaluation in package functions (I haven't done this yet, but it's on my to-do list for at least one of my packages), but you can't actually use this strategy for piping values to a specified argument or position 
with `.`.

It's worth pointing out that there is at least [some overhead with using pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35935105/2375551). It might be that best practice is to not actually use pipes at all in your package functions, which gets around the issue of using `.`. For the rest of NSE with `dplyr`commands, you can use quosures.

Comment: using `utils::globalVariables(".")` also works, but I'm not a big fan of it.  I worry that this might prevent a meaningful message when `.` gets used inappropriately.  I don't know what that might look like...I'm just generally paranoid.

Comment: How would using a quosure help here? Don't those just use symbols as parameters as well? Won't those still be undefined?

Comment: @MrFlick, you're right---your can use quosures for named columns and such, but there isn't a great way to deal with `.` itself.