# R: How to use rlangs .data feature in conjunction with magrittrs pipeline dot?

Tags: r, import, package, rlang

I am making an R-Package and I'm struggling with the imports in a way that pleases `R CMD check`. It gives me the `no visible binding for global variable '.'` Note.

I went searching and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57496617/10020441), which seems like [the best way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9439256/10020441) to deal with the issue.
But it raises a new problem since I can't seem to figure out how to use the `rlang .data` feature in conjunction with the `.` from `magrittr`.

Here is some nice and working code: `tibble(A=0:10,B=10:20) %>% .$A`
Now I'd like to change it to use the `rlang .data` feature. Something like this `tibble(A=0:10,B=10:20) %>% .data$A` exept that it's not working : `Error in .$.data : 3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2`

How can I use the `.data` feature in  conjunction with the `.` from `magrittr`? Or to put it more abstract: What is the best way to get rid of `R CMD check` `no visible binding for global variable '.'` Note?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.data` won't help here: it solves the problem for data masking, which is not what's happening with `.` (see also [dplyr . and _no visible binding for global variable '.'_ Note in package check](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48750221/4550695)).

I believe you have two choices: either don't use `.` inside the package, or follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57755406/4550695) and add

```
if (getRversion() >= "2.15.1") utils::globalVariables(c("."))
```

as a top-level call somewhere in your package source.