# Dplyr standard evaluation using a vector of multiple strings with mutate function

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, nse, standard-evaluation

I am trying to supply a vector that contains multiple column names to a `mutate()` call using the `dplyr` package. Reproducible example below:

```
stackdf <- data.frame(jack = c(1,NA,2,NA,3,NA,4,NA,5,NA),
                      jill = c(1,2,NA,3,4,NA,5,6,NA,7),
                      jane = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,NA,NA,NA))
two_names <- c('jack','jill')
one_name <- c('jack')

#   jack jill jane
#    1    1    1
#   NA    2    2
#    2   NA    3
#   NA    3    4
#    3    4    5
#   NA   NA    6
#    4    5   NA
#   NA    6   NA
#    5   NA   NA
#   NA    7   NA
```

I am able to figure out how to use the "one variable" versions, but do not know how to extend this to multiple variables?

```
# the below works as expected, and is an example of the output I desire
stackdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(test = anyNA(c(jack,jill)))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
    jack  jill  jane  test
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1     1     1 FALSE
 2    NA     2     2  TRUE
 3     2    NA     3  TRUE
 4    NA     3     4  TRUE
 5     3     4     5 FALSE
 6    NA    NA     6  TRUE
 7     4     5    NA FALSE
 8    NA     6    NA  TRUE
 9     5    NA    NA  TRUE
10    NA     7    NA  TRUE


# using the one_name variable works if I evaluate it and then convert to 
# a name before unquoting it
stackdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(test = anyNA(!!as.name(eval(one_name))))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
    jack  jill  jane  test
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1     1     1 FALSE
 2    NA     2     2  TRUE
 3     2    NA     3 FALSE
 4    NA     3     4  TRUE
 5     3     4     5 FALSE
 6    NA    NA     6  TRUE
 7     4     5    NA FALSE
 8    NA     6    NA  TRUE
 9     5    NA    NA FALSE
10    NA     7    NA  TRUE
```

How can I extend the above approach so that I could use the `two_names` vector? Using `as.name` only takes a single object so it does not work.

This question here is similar: [Pass a vector of variable names to arrange() in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497751/pass-a-vector-of-variable-names-to-arrange-in-dplyr). That solution "works" in that I can use the below code:

```
two_names2 <- quos(c(jack, jill))
stackdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(test = anyNA(!!!two_names2))
```

But it defeats the purpose if I have to type `c(jack, jill)` directly rather than using the `two_names` variable. Is there some similar procedure where I can use `two_names` directly? This answer [How to pass a named vector to dplyr::select using quosures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656993/how-to-pass-a-named-vector-to-dplyrselect-using-quosures) uses `rlang::syms` but though this works for selecting variables (ie `stackdf %>% select(!!! rlang::syms(two_names))` it does not seem to work for supplying arguments when mutating (ie `stackdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(test = anyNA(!!! rlang::syms(two_names)))`. This answer is similar but does not work: [How to evaluate a constructed string with non-standard evaluation using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053187/how-to-evaluate-a-constructed-string-with-non-standard-evaluation-using-dplyr?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several keys to solving this question:

- Accessing the strings within a character vector and using these with `dplyr`
- The formatting of arguments provided to the function used with `mutate`, here the `anyNA`

The goal here is to replicate this call, but using the named variable `two_names` instead of manually typing out `c(jack,jill)`.

```
stackdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(test = anyNA(c(jack,jill)))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
    jack  jill  jane  test
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1     1     1 FALSE
 2    NA     2     2  TRUE
 3     2    NA     3  TRUE
 4    NA     3     4  TRUE
 5     3     4     5 FALSE
 6    NA    NA     6  TRUE
 7     4     5    NA FALSE
 8    NA     6    NA  TRUE
 9     5    NA    NA  TRUE
10    NA     7    NA  TRUE
```

**1. Using dynamic variables with dplyr**

1. Using `quo`/`quos`: Does not accept strings as input. The solution using this method would be:

   ```
   two_names2 <- quos(c(jack, jill))
   stackdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(test = anyNA(!!! two_names2))
   ```

   Note that `quo` takes a single argument, and thus is unquoted using `!!`, and for multiple arguments you can use `quos` and `!!!` respectively. This is not desirable because I do not use `two_names` and instead have to type out the columns I wish to use.
2. Using `as.name` or `rlang::sym`/`rlang::syms`: `as.name` and `sym` take only a single input, however `syms` will take multiple and return a *list* of symbolic objects as output.

   ```
   > two_names
   [1] "jack" "jill"
   > as.name(two_names)
   jack
   > syms(two_names)
   [[1]]
   jack

   [[2]]
   jill
   ```

   Note that `as.name` ignores everything after the first element. However, `syms` appears to work appropriately here, so now we need to use this within the `mutate` call.

**2. Using dynamic variables within `mutate` using `anyNA` or other variables**

1. Using `syms` and `anyNA` directly does not actually produce the correct result.

   ```
   > stackdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(test = anyNA(!!! syms(two_names)))
       jack  jill  jane  test
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
    1     1     1     1 FALSE
    2    NA     2     2  TRUE
    3     2    NA     3 FALSE
    4    NA     3     4  TRUE
    5     3     4     5 FALSE
    6    NA    NA     6  TRUE
    7     4     5    NA FALSE
    8    NA     6    NA  TRUE
    9     5    NA    NA FALSE
   10    NA     7    NA  TRUE
   ```

   Inspection of the `test` shows that this is only taking into account the first element, and ignoring the second element. However, if I use a different function, eg `sum` or `paste0`, it is clear that both elements are being used:

   ```
   > stackdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(test = sum(!!! syms(two_names), 
                                               na.rm = TRUE))
       jack  jill  jane  test
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1     1     1     1     2
    2    NA     2     2     2
    3     2    NA     3     2
    4    NA     3     4     3
    5     3     4     5     7
    6    NA    NA     6     0
    7     4     5    NA     9
    8    NA     6    NA     6
    9     5    NA    NA     5
   10    NA     7    NA     7
   ```

   The reason for this becomes clear when you look at the arguments for `anyNA` vs `sum`.

   > function (x, recursive = FALSE)  .Primitive("anyNA")
   >
   > function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")

   `anyNA` expects a single object `x`, whereas `sum` can take a variable list of objects `(...)`.
2. Simply supplying `c()` fixes this problem (see answer from alistaire).

   ```
   > stackdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(test = anyNA(c(!!! syms(two_names))))
       jack  jill  jane  test
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
    1     1     1     1 FALSE
    2    NA     2     2  TRUE
    3     2    NA     3  TRUE
    4    NA     3     4  TRUE
    5     3     4     5 FALSE
    6    NA    NA     6  TRUE
    7     4     5    NA FALSE
    8    NA     6    NA  TRUE
    9     5    NA    NA  TRUE
   10    NA     7    NA  TRUE
   ```
3. Alternately... for educational purposes, one could use a combination of `sapply`, `any`, and `anyNA` to produce the correct result. Here we use `list` so that the results are provided as a single list object.

   ```
   # this produces an error an error because the elements of !!!
   # are being passed to the arguments of sapply (X =, FUN = )
   > stackdf %>% rowwise %>% 
       mutate(test = any(sapply(!!! syms(two_names), anyNA)))
   Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
     Evaluation error: object 'jill' of mode 'function' was not found.
   ```

   Supplying `list` fixes this problem because it binds all the results into a single object.

   ```
   # the below table is the familiar incorrect result that uses only the `jack`
   > stackdf %>% rowwise %>% 
       mutate(test = any(sapply(X=as.list(!!! syms(two_names)), 
                                FUN=anyNA)))

       jack  jill  jane  test
      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
    1     1     1     1 FALSE
    2    NA     2     2  TRUE
    3     2    NA     3 FALSE
    4    NA     3     4  TRUE
    5     3     4     5 FALSE
    6    NA    NA     6  TRUE
    7     4     5    NA FALSE
    8    NA     6    NA  TRUE
    9     5    NA    NA FALSE
   10    NA     7    NA  TRUE

   # this produces the correct answer
   > stackdf %>% rowwise %>% 
       mutate(test = any(X = sapply(list(!!! syms(two_names)), 
                         FUN = anyNA)))

   jack  jill  jane  test
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
    1     1     1     1 FALSE
    2    NA     2     2  TRUE
    3     2    NA     3  TRUE
    4    NA     3     4  TRUE
    5     3     4     5 FALSE
    6    NA    NA     6  TRUE
    7     4     5    NA FALSE
    8    NA     6    NA  TRUE
    9     5    NA    NA  TRUE
   10    NA     7    NA  TRUE
   ```

   Understanding why these two perform differently make sense when their behavior is compared!

   ```
   > as.list(two_names)
   [[1]]
   [1] "jack"

   [[2]]
   [1] "jill"

   > list(two_names)
   [[1]]
   [1] "jack" "jill"
   ```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `rlang::syms` (which is reexported by dplyr; alternately call it directly) to coerce strings to quosures, so

```r
library(dplyr)

stackdf <- data.frame(jack = c(1,NA,2,NA,3,NA,4,NA,5,NA),
                      jill = c(1,2,NA,3,4,NA,5,6,NA,7),
                      jane = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,NA,NA,NA))
two_names <- c('jack','jill')

stackdf %>% rowwise %>% mutate(test = anyNA(c(!!!syms(two_names))))
#> Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>     jack  jill  jane test 
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
#>  1    1.    1.    1. FALSE
#>  2   NA     2.    2. TRUE 
#>  3    2.   NA     3. TRUE 
#>  4   NA     3.    4. TRUE 
#>  5    3.    4.    5. FALSE
#>  6   NA    NA     6. TRUE 
#>  7    4.    5.   NA  FALSE
#>  8   NA     6.   NA  TRUE 
#>  9    5.   NA    NA  TRUE 
#> 10   NA     7.   NA  TRUE
```

Alternatively, using a little base R instead of tidy eval:

```r
stackdf %>% mutate(test = rowSums(is.na(.[two_names])) > 0)
#>    jack jill jane  test
#> 1     1    1    1 FALSE
#> 2    NA    2    2  TRUE
#> 3     2   NA    3  TRUE
#> 4    NA    3    4  TRUE
#> 5     3    4    5 FALSE
#> 6    NA   NA    6  TRUE
#> 7     4    5   NA FALSE
#> 8    NA    6   NA  TRUE
#> 9     5   NA   NA  TRUE
#> 10   NA    7   NA  TRUE
```

...which will likely be a lot faster, as iterating `rowwise` makes `n` calls instead of one vectorized one.

Comment: This actually is close but I encountered the same problem when I tried this approach. Can you see my answer? Calling the `list()` function appears to work, but it is not clear to me why `as.list` and `list` have different behavior here.

Comment: Oops edited. We both forgot the `c`; `!!!` splices them in as separate parameters, so the second was getting passed to `anyNA`'s `recursive` parameter, which is not correct.

Comment: why does one need `rowwise` at all? Isn't `mutate` row-wise anyway?

Comment: @Jelena-bioinf Not inherently; it depends on the function used in it, e.g. `+` returns a vector, but `sum` collapses everything to a single number (like `anyNA` here, so without `rowwise` it will return a single `TRUE` which `mutate` will recycle into a column). There are always alternatives to `rowwise` (it’s a discouraged idiom now), but they frequently require a deeper quiver of functions and understanding of functional programming.